# $.Zebra_Tooltips is not a constructor

Tags: jquery, wordpress, constructor, tooltip

I am using [zebra](https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Tooltips) tooltips plugin with jquery 1.12.4 (Wordpress)

I got `$.Zebra_Tooltips is not a constructor` error.

Here is my code:

```js
new  jQuery.Zebra_Tooltips($('.zebra_tooltips'), {
    'animation_speed':50,
    'animation_offset':10,
    'hide_delay':0,
    'show_delay':0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/zebra_tooltips@2.0.5/dist/css/default/zebra_tooltips.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/zebra_tooltips@latest/dist/zebra_tooltips.min.js"></script>

<p>
    <a href="javascript: void(0)"
       class="zebra_tooltips"
       title="Zebra Tooltips is a lightweight and highly configurable jQuery tooltips plugin">
        Over here!</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work.

Comment: Yes included top of custom.js. It is not about including files.

Comment: Answer updated with a snippet. You can see your code works. So, what's the issue?

Comment: @gaetanoM The code works in stackoverflow. It does not work in Wordpress

Comment: @Nat Can you create an evidence?  In Wordpress instead of $ you need to use the string jQuery. Moreover, did you include jQuery in Wordpress? Snippet updated.

Comment: @gaetanoM Please see my answer below re $ and jQuery. My only evidence is that I am including the same Zebra tooltips script in my Wordpress website and I get the same error. Yes jQuery is loaded and the script works if I use either of the 2 solutions in my answer. It does not work as written in the OP

Comment: @gaetanoM Thanks, but your updated snippet does not work in Wordpress either. I have spent a lot of time on this. Could only find solution as per my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two workarounds but as I do not have much knowledge of jQuery I'm not sure which is best nor whether they are both 'safe'.
Zebra_tooltips was not written to be used in Wordpress.

In the script they enclose all code in:

```
(function($) {
})($);
```

But in Wordpress '$' does NOT mean 'jQuery' as Wordpress has suppressed that (sorry if I'm not technically correct)

So the Zebra_tooltips script does not know that the final ($) means jQuery

Solution 1

Edit the Zebra_tooltips script so that the last line is

```
})(jQuery);
```

instead of

```
    })($);
```

This means you will have to do your own 'minification' of the Zebra_tooltips script and you will have to redo your edit if there is an update to Zebra_tooltips.

Solution 2

Add:

```
 var $=jQuery.noConflict();
```

to your own script, before you call Zebra_tools

This tells Zebra_tools (and Wordpress) that '$' means jQuery.

An issue I can see here is that if any other type of script (not jQuery) is also using $ then this may stop that other script from working.